# Custom react hook to set input form not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've tried creating a custom hook, following the examples an article about [handling forms in react using hooks](https://reactgo.com/react-hooks-forms/). I should also add I'm very new to react.

This is the content of `hooks/useInput.js`:

```
import { useState } from "react";

function useInput(initialValue) {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(initialValue);

  function handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.name);
    console.log(event.target.value);
    setValue(event.target.value);
  }

  return [value, handleChange];
}

export default useInput;
```

In a component I have the following:

```
import useInput from "hooks/useInput";

export default function Address(props) {
  const [fullName, setFullName] = useInput("");

  return (
    <FormControl fullWidth>
      <CustomInput
        required
        labelText="Full name"
        id="fullName"
        formControlProps={{
          fullWidth: true
        }}
        value={fullName}
        onChange={setFullName}
      />
    </FormControl>
  );
}
```

When I try to input some text (or even if I try to change the default state), nothing happens.
Any breakpoint that I set in useInput.js are not hit and no logging appears in the console.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: there seems to be a problem with your `CustomInput` component. try checking again. if you can't, try including the code from the `CustomInput` element as well.

Comment: And that was indeed the issue. I'll reply to the answer with more detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see your current input value with a button click you can see like this. I didn't even change your `userInput.js` file. I can see the updated value by doing this and console as well.

```js
export default function Address(props) {
    const [fullName, setFullName] = useInput("");
    return (
        <>
            <input
                placeholder="Name"
                value={fullName}
                onChange={setFullName}
            />
            <button onClick={() => {
                console.log(fullName);
            }}>Submit</button>
        </>
    );
}
```

Since I don't know about your `CustomInput`, I have written this with default `input` and `button`. Please check your `CustomInput` correctly. Because default `input` is working.

Comment: Spot on: the normal input works just fine. In fact, I should have mentioned that under the hood `CustomInput` uses MaterialUI, [in which docs](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/) it is stated that to alter an `input` element properties you should use `inputProps`. So, defining `inputProps={{value: fullName, onChange: setFullName}}` solves the problem.